# How to replace my current version by new version in the repository by svn?

Tags: svn

We use svn to collaboratively work on the source code. Now I would like to replace the soruce files that I have in my working directory by the new version of the source files that are located in the repository.

The first what comes to mind is to use `svn up`. However it does the following:

> This command syncs your local sand box with the server. If you have
>   made local changes, it will try and merge any changes on the server
>   with your changes on your machine.

And it is not exactly what I need because I do not want to merge my changes with the changes done by others. I just want to overwrite my source code (and, in this way, remove all the changes that I did to the code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the `svn revert` command. Followed by update.

```
revert: Restore pristine working copy file (undo most local edits).
usage: revert PATH...

  Note:  this subcommand does not require network access, and resolves
  any conflicted states.
```

Comment: Revert will return the working files into its original state.

Comment: @Michael: And than you update them to the latest. What's the problem with that?